# Register lambda as factory (with dependencies)

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm trying to migrate from [Grace](https://github.com/ipjohnson/Grace) IOC container to Autofac.

In Grace, I could do this kind of registration ([original source](https://github.com/ipjohnson/Grace/blob/2249282c57a06f23f7c93dd47cb78d7f5697cc1a/tests/Grace.Tests/DependencyInjection/Factory/ThreeArgFactoryTests.cs#L18)):

```
block.ExportFactory<SimpleObjectA, SimpleObjectB, SimpleObjectC, IEnumerable<ISimpleObject>>(
                    (a, b, c) => new List<ISimpleObject> { a, b, c });`
```

In summary, it takes a lambda expression as factory, whose arguments are resolved and supplied by the container to it.

In Autofac, all I have found is:

```
containerBuilder.Register((context, parameters) => new Service(...));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Autofac it's up to you to resolve the dependencies in the lambda. The registration you found is correct.

Let's say your lambda is `a => new Service(a)` and that's the factory. I say that because the Grace example you showed would [automatically be handled by Autofac supporting `IList<T>`](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html).

You'd register that like:

```cs
builder.Register(ctx =>
  {
    var a = ctx.Resolve<IDependency>();
    return new Service(a);
  });
```

If you want to [use parameters](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html), you can.

```cs
builder.Register((ctx, p) =>
  {
    var a = p.Typed<IDependency>();
    return new Service(a);
  });
```

However, there are even more things you can do which may also help, and for which I won't duplicate the documentation. It could be that you don't need to register a lambda at all, that Autofac will do some of this for you. You'll want to check out...

- [Auto-generated factories that allow parameters like `Func<A, B>`](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b)
- [Delegate factories](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) where you can provide some inputs as parameters and others from the container.

There are a lot of options here, it all depends on what you're trying to achieve... which isn't honestly 100% clear from the question. Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction.